# Where is the file located when path is not specified in Binary Writer?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I tried to look on the bin folder where the PEs are generated, but it is not saved there, I'm using ASP.NEt webforms

```
string tempExcelFilePath = "tempExcel.xls";
FileStream fs = new FileStream(tempExcelFilePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(fs);
bw.Write(fileBytes);//fileBytes is an array of bytes= byte[]
bw.Close();
```

Comment: In which folder/path do you have the class running this code? Check that folder

Comment: Have you stared the application via debugger? Then the file would be located under bin\Debug. I tried your code, and the file was saved in the bin folder

Comment: @Austin make your comment an answer so I can close it, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The full path of the file is stored at `fs.Name` in your code.

Answer (score 0):

C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\DevServer\10.0\tempExcel.xls

Comment: How are you sure OP's system configuration is exactly the same as yours?

Answer (score 0):

In general, when you give a Windows API call a filename that does not contain any path information (and the `FileStream` constructor eventually calls the Windows function), it will look for the file in the Current Directory, a per-process setting that determines, well, the Current Directory. This is true for relative paths, as well (that is, if you had specified "SubFolder\tempExcel.xls" as the filename.

You can easily determine the current directory in code using either the `System.Environment.CurrentDirectory` property or the `System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()` method. You can also set it (for the entire process, don't forget) using the same property, or `System.IO.Directory.SetCurrentDirectory()`

By default, I believe the current directory will be set to the location of the EXE that started the process - but there are things that could change that - a shortcut's "Starting Folder" parameter, for instance. Or any other piece of code that ran previously in the process and set hte Current Directory. FilePicker dialogs tend to do that.